# Proxy to simplify complex web pages

Tags: firefox, netbook, adblock, web-filtering

Web pages are becoming more and more bloated, so that the problem is not only the bandwidth needed to load them but also the processing power needed to render them. I currently use AdBlock with Firefox to get rid of some useless content, and on my smartphone I use Opera Mini, which filters pages and gives out a lightweight representation of the original page, using a filtering proxy. Needless to say, compared to Opera Mobile (without page filtering), complex pages are rendered smoothly and scroll well.

On my netbook (1 GHz, not very fast), some pages are very difficult to scroll because they are too crowded (an example: http://www.corriere.it, an italian newspaper, or Facebook), so AdBlock is not sufficient. It should be obvious that I don't consider upgrading to more powerful hardware.

I tried WebCleaner but gives me an error (MSVCR71.DLL missing) maybe because is 32-bit only and I'm using Windows 7 64-bit. This software looks like the ultimate solution.

I prefer a proxy than a firefox extension, because I would not be locked in with a specific software. Computers should be as modular as practically possible.

Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would focus on trying to fix the problem with WebCleaner. It is unlikely that this is because of a 64/32-bit conflict. And it does not seem to be a vast majority of viable alternatives to WebCleaner.

msvcr71.dll is a system file, and can be the cause of multiple problems regarding installation and use of new software. The first thing I recommend you to do is a scan and verification of all the system files to confirm that they are a-ok.

Here is how you do that:

1. Run CMD
2. Type 'sfc /SCANNOW' and let it finish

Alternatively if that does not work you could try a registry cleaner, such as [ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER).

These are the most simple solutions that I have at hand to fix your problem with the msvcr71.dll. If none of these prove successful I would point you in [this](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/msvcr71-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm) direction for other solutions.

Comment: I've already found the link you posted and tried `sfc /scannow` but I didn't have time to let it finish because looked like it would take half an hour. I'll try also to search the dll to see if it's really missing

Comment: a half hour to fix a problem is pretty minor, if it solves your problem. The suggestion here to run sfc /scannow does more than just check for file existence